# How to fix "Cannot call value of non-function type [UserInfo]" while trying to retrieve provider's data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve the FirebaseUser provider's data, but Swift debugger is returning the error

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[UserInfo]'

as can be seen in my code in the picture below:

[image: code]

```
let providData = userInstance.providerData {
    for profile in providerData {
        if profile.providerID == "facebook.com" {
            let fbUserId = profile.uid
            fbProfilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(fbUserId)/picture?height=300"
            self.profilePicUrl = fbProfilePicUrl
        }else if profile.providerID == "google.com" {
            let googleUserId = profile.uid
            //self.profilePicUrl = .....
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @Sh_Khan, it's done. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`providerData` is an array property of `FIRUser` check [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser), that you can't use **{** after it , so you need

```
for profile in user.providerData {
    if profile.providerID == "facebook.com" {
        let fbUserId = profile.uid
        fbProfilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(fbUserId)/picture?height=300"
        self.profilePicUrl = fbProfilePicUrl
    }else if profile.providerID == "google.com" {
        let googleUserId = profile.uid
        //self.profilePicUrl = .....
    }
}
```